# How to make multiple AI surround a player

Tags: unity, ai

I am working on a top-down RPG game and I have come across a problem. I am working on an AI system to allow the enemy AI to surround the player. I've been trying to keep my implementation really simple, however, I've been running into problems.

Here is what it currently looks like:
[image]
X represents the player and Y represents the friendly AI. There are 42 waypoints in total that the enemy can potentially occupy.

However, if any of the waypoints of the player object encounters an obstacle, or if another friendly AI is too close, it will disable those waypoints:
[image]
This poses a big problem because I do not have all 42 waypoints. From the looks of it, I might need something more dynamic in my case.

Are there any alternative ways to allow a large number of AI to surround the player or its allies?

Comment: Suggestion that isn't a full item: "force-based": you want AI to move towards the player, but you want the AI to stay away from other AI. You don't need a fixed set of points around the player.